# cxGrid hyperlink column issue

Tags: delphi, devexpress

In cxGrid, if I change the properties of a column to be a HyperLink type
then I must set its prefix to a desired link type (examples are `http` or `mailto`).

If I use `mailto:` then all of my records in the gird start showing that prefix 
(example: `mailto:john@gmail.com`) and that is what I am trying to avoid.

Is there a way I can eliminate that prefix from my email addresses that are in that column and retain the same functionality?

Basically, I need that prefix but I don't want it shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the column property UsePrefix to : UpOnlyOnExecute.